# How to pass json object to $eval function

Tags: puppeteer, apify

I am trying to pass the json to the function with no success
here is what I tried so far

```
await aHandle.$eval('input[name="date"]', (el) => (el.value =input.date)(input) );
```

or like this

```
await aHandle.$eval('input[name="date"]', (el) => (el.value =input.date),input );
```

or like this

```
await aHandle.$eval('input[name="date"]', (el) => (el.value =input.date) ).(input);
```

please advise the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
const Apify = require('apify');

Apify.main(async () => {
    const q = await Apify.openRequestQueue();
    await q.addRequest({ url: 'http://example.com' })

    const c = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
        requestQueue: q,
        handlePageFunction: async ({ page }) => {
            const inputServerSide = {
                date: '2019-09-26'
            };
            const aHandle = await page.$('div');
            await aHandle.$eval('h1', (el, inputClientSide) => {
                el.name = inputClientSide.date;
            }, inputServerSide );
            const name = await page.$eval('h1', (el) => el.name);
            console.log('Name:', name);
        }
    })

    await c.run();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> $eval(selector, pageFunction[, ...args])

The args/arguments are serialized, so you can pass the handle and extra data like this.

```
await aHandle.$eval(selector, (yourElementHandle, yourJsonData) => {
  yourElementHandle.value = yourJsonData.username
}, (yourJsonData) ); // <-- pass the handle and data here
```

Basically anything you pass after the function will be serialized and available to you in that function in that order.

It should work even without putting the braces `()`, since it's spreading the arguments.

Comment: since the yourElementHandle is not defined, This worked for me,await aHandle.$eval('input[name="date"]', (el,input) => {el.value =input.date},input );